# How can a Bash variable be used in a string passed to Bash?

Tags: bash, variables, echo, sudo

Let's say I've got the following here-document (which is used to enable hibernation in Ubuntu):

```
IFS= read -d '' text << "EOF"
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
EOF
```

I could store this text in a protected file in a way like the following:

```
echo "${text}" | sudo tee /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

How could I do a similar operation using the Bash variable in a command string (that's using the redirect operator) passed to Bash running under root?

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "${text}" > /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla'
```

In the new instance of Bash, the variable obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you say `sudo bash -c "echo \"$text\" > /etc/...."`? It works to me with these double quotes.

Comment: Not running the `echo` in `sudo` looks like the superior solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to pass the variable as an argument, like this:

```
sudo bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$0" > /path/to/output' "$text"
```

Comment: Very nice! I wasn't aware this could be done - and then, I wondered if it would start with `$1`. But no, the first one is `$0`.

Comment: @fedorqui it seems that this behaviour varied in the past but `$0` is the POSIX standard. See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152391/67817) for related discussion.

Comment: Arguably, the right thing to do is to pass a dummy (even empty) value to `bash` to preserve the semantics that `$1` is the first positional argument to the script: `bash -c '...' "make_output" "$text"` or `bash -c '...' "" "$text"`. (It really depends which you find more jarring; `$0` used as a positional parameter, or a seemingly unused argument to `bash`.)

Answer (score 0):

`text` variable is no more defined in the new `bash` environment, that is why it is failing.

This below command has been tested ok, give it a try:

```
 sudo bash -c 'cat  > /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla' <<<"${text}"
```